# ruby on rails current.user devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hola quiero guardar el nombre del usuario, auto es  boolean que cuando le clic guarde auto como true y el nombre del usuario

**Tipos de datos**:

```
 t.boolean :auto
 t.string  :nombresoli
```

**reuniones_controller.rb**:

```
def auto1
  r = Reunion.find(params[:id])
  r.nombresoli = User.find(current.user_id).name
  r.auto = true
  r.valid?
  p r.errors
  r.save(validate: false)

  redirect_to action: "show", id: r.id
end
```

**show.html.erb**:

```
<% if @reunion.auto == nil  %>
  <%= link_to 'Autorizar', auto1_path(@reunion.id) %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**:

```
  get 'reuniones/:id/auto1' => 'reuniones#auto1', as: :auto1
```

**Error**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Gemfile.rb**:

```
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.15'
```

Answer (score 1):

*Devise* utiliza el helper **`current_user`**, pero tu estás utilizando `current`, por eso te muestra error; para eliminarlo cambia `current.user_id` por `current_user.id` en el método `auto1`:

```
def auto1
  r = Reunion.find(params[:id])
  r.nombresoli = User.find(current_user.id).name
  r.auto = true
  r.valid?
  p r.errors
  r.save(validate: false)

  redirect_to action: "show", id: r.id
end
```